# Hide elements who have one of the selected classes per checkbox (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, select

I have some checkboxes and want to hide all elements who have the checked class. It's some kind of meals with incredients and I want the user to be able to hide all menus with e.g. "cheese".

I tried with "toggle" but there is a problem with it when I click further elements (thought it would be an easy task):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    $("." + inputValue).toggle();
  });
});
```

here is a fiddle:
[Hide elements who have class](https://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/p7Lvo2fd/)

Comment: What doesn't work? It looks okay to me.

Comment: Hm, I think "toggle" doesn't work here because when I click 1: dynamite, then 2: chocolate it's okay but then I click 3: strawberry and it toggles "dynamite" back.

Comment: I thought I had an easy solution - but it wasn't.  The problem you have is that there is no memory in the hidden article to say what check boxes you pressed to hide them.  So either you have to go back and read all the check boxes again when you are toggling them back on, or.... let me think!

Comment: Take a look at my answer below - it uses CSS to do all the hiding and makes it easier to program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably something more along the lines of this. (Explanation/comments included in the code)

https://jsfiddle.net/p7Lvo2fd/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

    //Show all articles
    $("article").show();

    //Get checked boxes
    var $checkedBoxes = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");

    //For each checked box, hide the associated articles
    $checkedBoxes.each(function() {
        $("article").filter("." + $(this).val()).hide();
    });

  });
});
```

Or if you prefer a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $("article").show();
    var $checkedBoxes = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
    $checkedBoxes.each(function() {
      $("article").filter("." + $(this).val()).hide();
    })
  });
});
```

```css
article {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="incredientsCheckbox" value="dynamite"> dynamite</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="incredientsCheckbox" value="chocolate"> chocolate</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="incredientsCheckbox" value="strawberry"> strawberry</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="incredientsCheckbox" value="cheese"> cheese</label>
</div>

<article class="strawberry dynamite"><strong>classes:</strong> dynamite - strawberry</article>
<article class="strawberry chocolate"><strong>classes:</strong> strawberry - chocolate</article>
<article class="strawberry"><strong>classes:</strong> strawberry</article>
<article class="cheese"><strong>classes:</strong> cheese</article>
<article class="cheese dynamite strawberry"><strong>classes:</strong> cheese - dynamite - strawberry</article>
```

---

For a more clear implementation, you can also see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/p7Lvo2fd/5/

It changes the background instead of hiding the items, so it's easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

Add to CSS these switches

```
.dynamite_hide {display: none}
.strawberry_hide {display: none}
.chocolate_hide {display: none}
.cheese_hide {display: none}
```

Change your click handler to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).attr("value")
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $("." + val).addClass(val+"_hide")
    else
      $("." + val).removeClass(val+"_hide")
  });
});
```

Comment: Also `if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $("." + val).addClass(val+"_hide")
    else
      $("." + val).removeClass(val+"_hide")` could simply be `$("." + val).toggleClass(val+"_hide",this.checked);`

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to do this on the change, not the click event - that way if you change via script it works. If you have preset values, you can trigger the change on startup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var checks = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    //show all then hide checked stuff
    $('article').show();
    checks.each(function(index, item) {
      $('article').filter(function() {
        return $(this).hasClass($(item).val());
      }).hide();// hit DOM once, hide them
    });
  }).trigger("change");
});
```

Smaller filter, but does same thing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var checks = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    //show all then hide checked stuff
    $('article').show();
    checks.each(function(index, item) {
      $('article').filter("."+item.value).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

**Most efficient:**

Now that we understand the concept, we can get a class list as a selector list and use that, saving hitting the DOM on each class found checked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var classes = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
      return "." + this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
    $('article').show().filter(classes).hide();
  }).trigger("change");
});
```